# Nestjs + TypeORM Mssql connection with managed identity or passwordless connection

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, typeorm, azure-managed-identity, password-less

How to connect to mssql database using managed identity with TypeORM ?
Currently, I'm creating the connection as below:

```
createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
    name: 'default',
    type: 'mssql',
    host: this.configService.get<string>("DATABASE_HOST"),
    port: Number(this.configService.get<number>("DATABASE_PORT")) ,
    username: this.configService.get<string>("DATABASE_USERNAME"),
    password: this.configService.get<string>("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
    database: this.configService.get<string>("DATABASE_DB"),
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true, 
    ...}}
```

I'm looking something similar to this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-nodejs?view=azuresql-mi&tabs=macos
Use Azure App Service Managed Identity to connect to the SQL database

```
const config = {
    server: process.env["db_server"],
    port: process.env["db_port"],
    database: process.env["db_database"],
    authentication: {
    type: 'azure-active-directory-msi-app-service'
    },
    options: {
    encrypt: true
    }
    }
```

Or is there a way to pass the database connection object while intializing Repositories ?
Thankyou for your time!

Comment: Could you share the code for your `ConfigService`? It looks like Azure just provides environment variables, so you should only need to get those values from the environment in your config service.

Comment: I've recently tried to find an answer to this and it looks like it's currently "maybe". There is an open issue in TypeORM, but people are reporting it working. They use tedious under the covers so it's technically possible: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/10762